# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 't' with multiprocessing in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, python-multiprocessing

Anaconda Spyder console (Windows 7) recently poped new bug for me:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> def t():
...     print 1
... 
>>> p = mp.Process(target = t)
>>> p.start()
>>> p.join()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 381, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\pickle.py", line 1126, in find_class
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 't'
>>>
```

Though in IDLE (Python 2.7) it works fine:

```
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> def t():
        print 1
>>> p = mp.Process(target = t)
>>> p.start()
>>> p.join()
>>>
```

It also works good on Fedora Anaconda:

```
Python 2.7.10 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:03) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> def t():
...     print 1
... 
>>> import multiprocessing as mp
>>> p = mp.Process(target = t)
>>> p.start()
>>> 1
p.join()
>>> 
>>>
```

How i can debug this? What should i look for or what i can do to fix this?

Comment: I think this is more of an issue on how Anaconda deals with the `__main__` module on Windows (or maybe it cannot do it another way?). This is a common issue with interactive interpreter. This is also specified in the doc [multiprocessing Windows](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#windows)

Comment: Yep, update is misleading then, thank you.